# JQuery datatables loading error: sValue is undefined

Tags: datatables

I am using JQuery DataTables v1.8.2 to filter my tables. 
I have quicktabs that each loads a different table . When the page loads, quicktab 1 is opened, table 1 is loaded and filtering is done successfully. However, when moving to quicktab 2, an error in the console is showed:"TypeError: sValue is undefined".
Another scenario, when the page loads, quicktab 2 is opened, table 2 is loaded, filtering is done successfully also. So the issue is that the first load is done successfully, second load for another table shows the error.

sValue is a variable in dataTables library, I am using the following:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you want anything but wild guesses, I suggest you add some code to your question so we have a chance to analyze the problem.

Comment: The code I used is in the link. anw thanks I solved the problem it was a duplication on the footer of the table:)